# Contact Form 7 - Change email content after field replacement

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make the text in the email that is sent to the admin all caps. I have gotten all caps to work, but the placeholders ([first-name], [last-name], [email], etc.) are not being replaced with the values. I don't know how to use the strtoupper() function on the email body AFTER the placeholders have been replaced.

This is my current code:

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_all_caps_email");

function wpcf7_all_caps_email($WPCF7_ContactForm)
{
    //Get current form
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    // get current SUBMISSION instance
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    // Ok go forward
    if ($submission) {
        // get submission data
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // nothing's here... do nothing...
        if (empty($data)) {
            return;
        }

        $mail = $wpcf7->prop('mail');
        $mail['body'] = strtoupper($mail['body']);
        

        // Save the email body
        $wpcf7->set_properties(array(
            "mail" => $mail
        ));
        // return current cf7 instance
        return $wpcf7;
    }
}
```

This is what the mail that comes through looks like:

```
FROM:
[YOUR-NAME]

EMAIL:
[YOUR-EMAIL]

PHONE:
[YOUR-PHONE]

COMPANY: (EMPTY IF NOT ENTERED)
[COMPANY-NAME]

EVENT DATE:
[_FORMAT_EVENT-DATE "F JS Y"]

EVENT LOCATION INFORMATION:
[EVENT-ADDRESS]
[EVENT-CITY]

VENUE:
[VENUE-NAME]

NUMBER OF GUESTS:
[NUMBER-OF-GUESTS]

DELIVERY REQUESTED?
[DELIVERY]

MESSAGE:
[YOUR-MESSAGE]

REQUESTED ITEMS:

[YITH-REQUEST-A-QUOTE-LIST]
```

Comment: its unclear how your setting `$data` in the mail anyway but if you want the inputted content uppercase you should use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) on $_POST, or presume $data, rather then doing it on the template

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence. There is some unused code in there because I copied it from another post and I wasn't sure what to remove. I feel like there is something else I need to apply the strtoupper() function to, but I can't figure out what that is or how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert all of the text from the email to uppercase, you have to do this after the string replacement is done.  With that being the case, you'll have to use the filter `wpcf7_mail_components` this is applied after the string replacement, but before the email is actually sent.

This filter passes the mail components in an array.  Then you want to use `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML and make all of the text uppercase.

With this being the case, you can use the format of your cf7 `form tags` in standard upper or lower case like `[text your-field]`

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'dd_mail_componentns', 10, 1 );
function dd_mail_componentns( $components ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $components['body'] );
    $xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    foreach ( $xPath->query( '/html/body//text()' ) as $text ) {
        $text->data = strtoupper( $text->data );
    }
    $components['body'] = $dom->saveXML( $dom->documentElement );
    return $components;
}
```

This has been tested and works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I cleaned up the code, but the email is still coming through with the placeholders instead of the actual content.

Comment: So you want the submitted data to be all caps?  You can make the rest of the email as you want... right?

Comment: Close. I want everything in the email to be in all caps. Basically, I want to grab whatever the message is, convert it to caps, put that new date in and send the email.

Comment: After the dynamic data, short codes have been rendered, etc.

Comment: In the form tag in the `form` tab name your fields in caps.  like `[text VENUE-NAME]`

Comment: I can do that, but the values the user fills in won’t be in caps. I need everything to be in caps. Plus, there is another plugin that fills the email with content. Really what I need to figure out is how to grab the rendered email body, make everything uppercase, then put that content back in and send the email.

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: YES! This did it!! I was SO stuck! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad it worked out. You can upvote the answer as well if helped you.